# Algorithm to minimize number of operations in multiplication of a binary matrix by a vector

Tags: algorithm, matrix, optimization, greedy

Let D be a type of object which defines the plus and minus operators (to give more context, D is a large matrix of real numbers with fixed dimensions).

The plus operator is associative and commutative and returns another object of type D.
The minus operator also returns an object of type D and is defined so that

```
x = y-z   <=>  y = x + z
```

Let A be a binary matrix of size (n,m) and b a vector of elements of type D of size m. Let y=Ab be the matrix product of A and b.

For example, if the matrix A is

```
A = [ 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
      1 1 1 0 0 0 0
      1 1 1 1 0 0 0
      0 0 1 1 0 0 0
      1 1 1 1 1 1 0
      1 1 1 1 1 1 1
    ]
```

Then, using a brute force approach and skipping zeros, we can compute y=Ab as

```
y0 = b0 + b1 + b3
y1 = b0 + b1 + b2
y2 = b0 + b1 + b2 + b3
y3 = b2 + b3
y4 = b0 + b1 + b2 + b3 + b4 + b5
y5 = b0 + b1 + b2 + b3 + b4 + b5 + b6
```

The number of additions required to obtain the results is the number of ones in the matrix A minus the number of rows. In the example above, there are 25-6=19 additions.

By introducing a few temporary variables zi, we could transform the calculation in the example above as:

```
z0 = b0 + b1
z1 = b2 + b3
z2 = z0 + z1
z3 = z2 + b4 + b5
y0 = z0 + b3
y1 = z0 + b2
y2 = z2
y3 = z1
y4 = z3
y5 = z3 + b6
```

which reduces the number of additions to 8.

I would like to devise an algorithm which generates a computation plan to minimize the number of additions, via opportunistically introducing temporary variables. Subtractions might also be allowed and have the same cost as additions.

Comment: `number of ones in the matrix A minus the number of rows` assuming non-zero rows.

Comment: Seems like a variation on the [exact cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover).  The goal is an exact cover of multiple sets, while reusing the same subsets as much as possible. In other words, you've taken a hard problem, and made it even harder.

Comment: Isn't this "just" CSE (CommonSubexpressionElimination)? Using subtraction to get sums of fewer terms from longer sums is never an improvement *with sequential execution*.

Comment: Yes, it is a form of CSE.  However what specific algorithm to employ to achieve that is not clear.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are aware of this, but you can typically find even a lower number of operations if you allow subtractions as well. Right now you seem focused only on additions. This would significantly change your problem.